# Dudas con el siguiente modelo Entidad Relación

Tags: modelorelacional

Tengo que plasmar la siguiente actividad en un modelo Entidad/Relación:

> Una  empresa  decide  informatizar  su  nómina.  Del  resultado  del
> análisis  realizado,  se  obtienen  las siguientes informacionesa
> partir de las cuales se pide el modelo E/R correspondiente:
>
> -A cada empleado se le entregan múltiples nóminas a lo largo de su vida laboral y al menos una mensualmente.
>
> -A cada empleado se le identifica porel NIF del empleado, nombre, edad, número de hijos, nº de trienios, porcentaje de retención para
> hacienda, datos de cuenta corriente en la que se ingresa el dinero
> (banco, sucursal y número de cuenta) y departamentos en los que
> trabaja.
>
> -Un empleado puede trabajar en varios departamentos y en cada uno de ellos trabajará con una determinadafunción que puede ser la misma en
> distintos departamentos.
>
> -De un departamento interesa tenerun código, sunombre y cada  una de sus posibles sedes.-De las sedes interesa tener un Código y una
> localización.
>
> -Un  departamento  tiene  al  menos  una  sede  y  en  una  sede  pueden  residir  más  de  un departamento.
>
> -La  distinción  entre  dos  nóminas  se  hará  además  de  mediante  el  códigodel  empleado,  conel ejercicio fiscal (año),el número de
> mes al que pertenece y con un número de orden en el caso de
> habervarios justificantes de nómina recibidos en el mismo mes.
>
> -Cada  justificante  de nómina  consta  de  varias  líneas  (  al  menos  una es  uningresos  )  y  cada línea  se  identifica  por  un
> número  de  línea.  Una  línea  puede  corresponder  a  un  ingreso  o
> a  un descuento. En ambos casos, se recoge la cantidad que corresponde
> a la línea ( en positivo si se trata de un ingreso o en negativo si es
> un descuento ). En el caso de los descuentos se recoge además la base
> sobre la cual se aplica y el porcentaje que se aplica para el cálculo
> de estos.
>
> -Toda  línea  de  un  ingreso  de  un  justificante  de  nómina  corresponde  a  un  único  concepto retributivo.-De los conceptos
> retributivos se mantiene un código y una descripción. -De  cara  a  la
> contabilidad  de  la  empresa  cada  línea  de  un  justificante  de
> nómina  se  imputa  al menos  a  un  elemento  de  coste  (comisiones,
> horas extras, sueldo, vacaciones......).  Al  mismo elemento de coste
> pueden imputársele varias líneas.
>
> -Para cada elemento de coste se recoge un código, una descripción y un saldo.-Entre los elementos de coste se establece una jerarquía, en el
> sentido en que un elemento de coste puede contener a otros elementos
> de coste, pero un elemento de coste solo puede estar contenido en, a
> lo sumo, otro elemento de coste.
>
> -En  determinadas  fechas  que  se  deben  recoger,  un  apunte  contable  (código  de  apunte y cantidad) se liquida con cargo auno o
> varios elementos de coste y a una o varias transferencias bancarias
> caracterizadas  por  un  código,  los  datos  de  cuenta  corriente
> (banco,  sucursal  y número  de  cuenta)  y  cantidad.  Por  cada
> apunte  contable  y  transferencia    bancaria  se  pueden liquidar
> varios elementos de coste.

Esto es lo que llevo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Por favor, no le prestéis atención a los atributos faltantes, esa parte ya la haré**

El último párrafo no consigo entenderlo ni veo manera de implementarlo en mi modelo entidad relación. Creo que un apunte contable es una entidad, pero no sé con qué otras entidades debe relacionarse. Otra posibilidad es que no sea una entidad sino una relación, pero no estoy seguro, ¿Me podéis ayudar?

Gracias.

Comment: No sería más fácil preguntarle a quien te dejo esta tarea acerca de lo que es un apunte contable?, Si los demás aquí no sabemos acerca de ese término solo vamos a estar especulando y probablemente dando respuestas erróneas

Comment: Sí, eso ya lo intenté. Pero todavía no me ha contestado. Tampoco tengo idea de lo que es un apunte contable; pero las clases se han suspendido y no parece que me vayan a contestar pronto.

No obstante, si no podéis ayudarme por falta de información, gracias igualmente.